# Not able to access instance after Sitecore setup as Azure App Service from marketplace

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore-azure

I have setup Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 as Azure App Service using Marketplace.
The setup completed and i got urls for cm and cd like
xxxxxx-cd.azurewebsites.net and 
xxxxxx-cm.azurewebsites.net

But when I access these URLs I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoNhx.png) screen.

Also xxxxxx-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore gives page not found.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

According to your screen, the `Azure App Service` has been created, but there is nothing inside it. Seem like something went wrong and deployment script didn't deploy Sitecore's file to App Service. You can verify it using App Service Editor tool.

The reason why deployment went wrong could be this known issue: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/755670.